# Spectrogram in python using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, fft, spectrogram

I need to make spectrogram using numpy. I take 1s of audio and split it into 0.02s chunks. Then I calculate FFT using numpy and put it back together into one image. Results are poor.

Here is spectrogram generated using matplotlib specgram function:

[image]

And here is my 'spectrogram':

[image]

Here is my code:

```
spect_frags = []
transform = []

for x in range(0, 8000, 160):
  spect_frags.append(spect_sample[x:x + 160])

for sample in spect_frags:
  transform.append(abs(np.fft.fft(sample).real)[0:np.fft.fft(sample).real.size//4])
```

I cut out 3/4 of frequencies beacuse I don't need them for now.
I have no clue why there is so much diffrence in resolution. How can I improve it?

Comment: Are you taking the log of the result? It looks like matplotlib is

Comment: Show a proper MCVE. Make a random dataset, and show how you generate both images.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you need to apply a windowing function to get the same results

Comment: Could you add more details about the input and the desired output. Also post the complete code you used, including the call to matplotlib that seems to be your desired output.

Comment: Try to take logarithm before displaying results

Comment: @tstanisl I've tried and results are better, but still far away from matplotlib method.

Comment: You may consider to remove the dead link in your post. Next time it would be better if you update the post instead to make the information persistent and available to other users. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Spectrogram MCVE

You can recreate a crude estimate of `specgram` with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read some sample file (replace with your data):
rate, data = wavfile.read('./data/aaaah.wav')
# rate=48000, data.shape=(46447, 2) ~ almost 1s of stereo signal

# Spectrogram estimation:
N = 256
S = []
for k in range(0, data.shape[0]+1, N):
    x = fft.fftshift(fft.fft(data[k:k+N,0], n=N))[N//2:N]
    # assert np.allclose(np.imag(x*np.conj(x)), 0)
    Pxx = 10*np.log10(np.real(x*np.conj(x)))
    S.append(Pxx)
S = np.array(S)

# Frequencies:
f = fft.fftshift(fft.fftfreq(N, d=1/rate))[N//2:N]
# array([    0. ,   187.5,   375. , ..., 23625. , 23812.5])

# Spectrogram rendering:
plt.imshow(S.T, origin='lower')
```

It outputs:

[image]

When [`specgram`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.html) renders:

```
_ = plt.specgram(data[:,0])
```

[image]

This MCVE differs from `specgram` because axes should be scaled to properly reflect time and frequencies and there is no moving windowing. More precisely:

- x-axis stands for time chunck index of length `N=256`;
- y-axis is positive half plane FFT index (`N//2=128`), notice the use of `fftshift` to assemble the spectrum after `fft`;
- real frequencies are available using sampling rate and `fftfreq`, in `specgram` it ranges from 0 to 1 as this method is not necessarily aware of the signal sampling rate;
- there is no window overlap (independent contiguous chuncks are used), this is why the MCVE is a bit less smooth than `specgram`.

### Power estimate

Also notice than taking real part of complex number is not the same as taking the magnitude. Mainly, when you write:

```
abs(np.fft.fft(sample).real)
```

You are not taking the norm of complex number, but you totally remove the complex part because of the `.real` call.

You should [estimate the power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) using [product of conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate):

```
10*np.log10(np.real(x*np.conj(x)))
```

Then use `abs` to transform `complex` type (or just keep the `real` part as the complex part must be null) into `float`.  Finally, you can scale in [Decibel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) using decimal logarithm.

#### Sanity check

You can check the result of FFT is indeed of complex type with a significative complex part (removing it leads to information loss):

```
x
# array([-1.56000000e+02-0.00000000e+00j, -3.94271344e+01+1.17935735e+02j,
#         4.03754070e+01+4.14695163e+01j,  1.71510716e+01+1.26920718e+01j,
#         2.15523795e+01-2.07362424e+00j, -3.03847433e+00-1.22767815e+01j,
#        -4.56347533e+00-7.36380957e-01j, -1.28048283e+01-6.80931256e+00j,
#        -2.22781473e+01+1.12096897e+01j, -1.13788549e+01+2.54314337e+01j,
#        ...])
```

And the product of conjugates do have a null complex part (but is still of `complex` type):

```
x*np.conj(x)
# array([2.43360000e+04+0.j, 1.54633365e+04+0.j, 3.34989427e+03+0.j,
#        4.55247945e+02+0.j, 4.68804979e+02+0.j, 1.59951690e+02+0.j,
#        2.13675640e+01+0.j, 2.10330365e+02+0.j, 6.21972990e+02+0.j,
#        7.76236159e+02+0.j, 1.05846430e+03+0.j, 6.54663598e+02+0.j,
#        6.95792718e+01+0.j, 6.03013130e+01+0.j, 1.11620428e+01+0.j,
#        ...])
```

You can ensure this is always true (sanity check), by asserting the following:

```
assert np.allclose(np.imag(x*np.conj(x)), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

For efficient use with [JAX](https://github.com/google/jax) I found it useful to adapt [@jlandercy](/users/3067485/)'s solution to avoid explicit loops and to add some simple Hann windowing. I gave up support for stereo input in the process, although I'm fairly certain that the whole point of computing STFT is that the nonlinearity of Fourier transforms means I'm destroying some information by collapsing stereo signals to mono before carrying this out.

I also did not extend their answer to include overlapping windows in the interest of preserving its simplicity and concision. There's probably some numpy sorceress out there who knows how to do efficient `np.concatenate` to stitch together or interpolate slices of nonoverlapping signal samples from the innermost dimensions of `wins` or some such. Regrettably, I myself have no such knowledge of the dark arts, so that functionality has been elided.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import jax.numpy as jnp

def stft(a, n_fft=128, window=jnp.hanning):  
  n = n_fft
  rpad = n - a.shape[-1] % n
  wins = jnp.pad(a, (0, rpad)).reshape(-1, n) * window(n)
  fftc = jnp.fft.fftshift(jnp.fft.fft(wins, n=n))[..., n // 2 : n]
  fftr = jnp.real(fftc * jnp.conj(fftc))
  return fftr

audio =  # buffer single-channel floating-point samples from somewhere...
_ = plt.imshow(stft(audio, 1024).T[:, -512:], cmap="viridis")
```

[image: demo spectrogram]